# Change Jetty URL

Tags: java, jetty

I have just set up a basic Jetty project named music-store-api. To access my project through Jetty I would go to `http://localhost:8090/music-store-api/hello-world`. I am wondering how I would remove the music-store-api part from the URL so it becomes `http://localhost:8090/hello-world`?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `context path` to root, aka "/".

Depending on how you have your music app deployed, there's a few different ways to accomplish this.

Since you are using `jetty-maven-plugin` and it's `jetty:run` goal, you'll need to edit your `pom.xml`.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
  <configuration>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <webApp>
      <contextPath>/</contextPath> <!-- this line is the important one -->
    </webApp>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

From: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-your-webapp

Comment: To run Jetty, I go to: IntelliJ -> Maven -> music-store-api -> Plugins -> jetty -> jetty:run. I also have a `jetty.xml` and `web.xml`. Is this the information you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions tp modify the `contextPath` on https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-specific-webapp-deployment.html